# C++ Pointers to Pointers in Java

Tags: java

I am a Java noob.  I have been able to grasp the concept of converting C/C++ pointers into Java references and this has gone fairly smoothly.

I hit a piece of code that has pointers to pointers (ie **ptr).  I need to dereference the pointer and change the value of the pointer it is pointing to (ie  *ptr = &newthing;)

This seems alot tougher in java.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?  Quick google search turned up nothing.

Here's a code example in C++.  I want to get something similar working in java but the ptr_to_ptr variable is a problem:

```
struct _coord
{
   int x;
   int y;
   _coord * next_coordinate;
} coordinate_t;   

coordinate_t buffer[100];
coordinate_t * head;
coordinate_t ** ptr_to_ptr;

if (wednesday)
{
    ptr_to_ptr = &head;
}
else
{
    ptr_to_ptr = &head->next_coordinate;
}
*ptr_to_ptr = &buffer[3];   // <<<---- HOW DO YOU MAKE THIS WORK?
```

Comment: Erm, Java doesn't have pointers?

Comment: @KazekageGaara The OP is talking about what a "pointer to pointer" in c++ would translate to in Java.

Comment: Java doesn't let the programmer use pointers or pointer arithmetic like C/C++. It will be better if you post what your specific problem is (including code fragment would be good depending on the problem).

Comment: the solution depends on your specific problem since java does not support pointer-to-pointer directly.(for example it is impossible to point to a reference on the stack)

Comment: OK, I posted a code example in C++ to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.  I could not find any easy way to do a pointer to a pointer (reference to a reference) in java.  So I refactored the code to use arrays of references, and array indices instead of pointers.  I *think* this will work (it coded easily) but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: This worked.  It's ugly code but if you REALLY need to port C++ code with alot of pointers to java, it can be done using classes for the structures and pointers and pointers to pointers.  I won't post the code, it's too ugly.  But it served my purpose and runs faster than array lookups since I am tricking java into using references as "pointers".

Comment: You should consider accepting @dasblinkenlight's answer since he's the first to suggest using arrays

Answer (score 15):

A typical trick one could use to model pointers to pointers in Java is using arrays: a reference to the array itself serves as the "pointer", while the array element serves as the item pointed to. You can nest these as much as you'd like, but the code does not look nearly as nice as it does in C/C++.

Rather than porting C/C++ idioms into Java, you should build a mutable class that lets you change the item inside it. This class would serve as a "pointer" to give you the functionality that you are looking for, and it would also add readability to your Java code. Generics greatly simplify your task, requiring only one implementation that you could reuse.

Answer (score 4):

Well pointer to pointer is not directly mappable in Java. I assume you want to assign a new object to a pointer inside a function.

As far as I know you can only solve this by using a wrapper object that acts as a reference, so you can modify the real reference inside:

```
class ObjRef {

   public RealObj obj;

}

void modifyRef(ObjRef ref){

   ref.obj = new RealObj()

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This pretty much is the code that dasblinkenlight is describing in his answer.

Comment: @Joe And I provided it. Besides, he's using arrays, I'm not.

Comment: He's also described creating a mutable class with Generics which would actually be a more reusable solution. Read the entire post before you get defensive.

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry if it sounded like I'm disagreing about our approach beeing similar. But it sounded to me like you think me post was redundant.

Comment: Your post isn't necessarily redundant as code is always nice to show.  Your description though is lacking compared to his.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have pointers. But one can say that when you create an `Object`, you are creating a reference(pointer) to that `Object`.

For example:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

So the reference `obj` is actually pointing to the new `Object` you just created.

Now, if you want to translate the concept of pointer to a pointer, you could simply create a reference that would point to an existing reference.

```
Object obj = new Object();
Object obj2;
obj2 = obj;
```

Comment: No, that's a copy.  Obj2 and obj are pointing at the same object.  I need a reference to an object that references an object.

Comment: @Batdude Ok. My answer is a wrong answer, but still I will let it stay, because your question seems like the one that will be searched by many people. So my post will let them know that the concept I offered was totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The only "pointer-like" method is unsafe() . You can allocate memory with it. But you cannot go outside the JVM area :)