# Pointer to pointer equivalent in java

Tags: java, c, pointers

For last some day I am learning Java while I have some knowledge in C. Now I am trying to convert code written in C to a Java code. There I found a pointer to pointer (`pptr`)variable declaration like this -

```
   int  n;
   int  *ptr;
   int  **pptr;

   n = 13; 
   ptr = &n;
   pptr = &ptr;
```

As far as I know, in Java there is no pointer type variable. My question is there any way to represent `pptr` or anything equivalent of `pptr` in Java?

Comment: No, and it is a good thing ;)

Comment: What would *pointer to a pointer* mean if there is no *pointer*? What are you trying to achieve in the code is the real question, and that would beg an alternative answer in Java not using pointers.

Comment: @ortis why is it good? Is it because some programmers can't handle the complexity of working with pointers?

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to pointer? Is it for an array of arrays? For every appropriate use of a pointer to pointer in C, Java has an approach that works without it.

Comment: @iharob the same sort of thought process tyrannical governments use to force their citizens to do what they want and also why they removed `goto`.

Comment: This has already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126782/c-pointers-to-pointers-in-java

Comment: @lodo not necessarily you could want to alter the content of the pointer in the sense that you make it point somewhere else, and hence a pointer to pointer is also useful in that situation, I suppose in java there would be a pass by reference to achieve the same.

Comment: @iharob there are ways to achieve what you say in Java without pointers. Just use a wrapper object (maybe a Pointer<T>) or an array of length 1.

Comment: `pointer is not good` this sounds like an good excuse for programmers to hide behind some other languages after they fail to manage pointers instead of trying to improve themselves.

Comment: to the question itself, it's hard to believe it's still good to employ the exact structure when porting from c to java.

Comment: Java and C are languages with different philosophies. Java is Object-Oriented, C isn't. Java is memory-managed, C isn't. An attempt to just convert C code to Java code is not going to result in good or readable Java code, even if you find a workaround for pointers. I suggest learning the language properly, and then you'll be able to translate idioms of C into idioms of Java rather than do a "word-by-word" translation that will look like Google Translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.  But first, a lesson in Java...

In Java, whenever you use objects, pointers are involved.  If you have an object, the variable that "holds" that object is actually a pointer to that object.  So if you are working with objects, you are already using pointers.

Now for primitive data types (e.g., integers, chars, or floating point numbers), Java does not use pointers, though. So if you want pointers for primitive data types, you need to use a [wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class), such as `Integer`, which effectively promotes the value to an object.

Note, however, that the default wrapper classes are immutable.

If you want double-pointers (a pointer to a pointer) or triple pointers, you will need to create custom wrapper classes, like an `ObjectWrapper` class, that allows you to set up an arbitrary number of objects each pointing to (or "holding") the next.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at some of the use cases for multiple indirection in C, and see how they apply to Java.

**Use Case #1**: you want a function or method to change the value of a pointer or reference parameter such that it points to a new object, and have that change reflected in the caller.

In C, that would look something like this:

```
void foo( T **p ) 
{
  *p = new_value(); // update the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T *var;      // for any type T
  foo( &var ); // foo will set var to point somewhere else
}
```

`var` is a pointer to something, and we want the function `foo` to change `var` such that it points to something else.  Since C passes all function arguments by value, if we want `foo` to update `var`, we must pass a pointer to `var`, giving us a pointer to pointer type in `foo`.

Java doesn't expose operations on pointer types (no unary `&` address-of or `*` indirection operators), so we can't do this directly.  We'd have to wrap the reference we want to change in *another* reference type and pass that wrapper type to the method, and even then I'm not sure it would do the same thing as the C code above:

```
public class thing
{
   // attributes
}

public class thingWrapper {
{
  public thing t;
}

public void pointToNewThing( thingWrapper tw )
{
  tw.t = newThing();
}

public void bar()
{
  thing t = new thing();
  ...
  thingWrapper tw = new thingWrapper();
  tw.t = t;
  pointToNewThing( tw );
  t = tw.t;
  ...
}
```

**Use Case #2**: you want to allocate a multi-dimensional array in a piecemeal fashion, rather than in a single operation.  This is useful if you want a "jagged" array (where the number of elements in each row isn't uniform) or if you're trying to allocate *a lot* of memory and don't have a single available block large enough for the whole thing.

In C, you'd do something like

```
T **arr = malloc( N * sizeof *arr );
if ( arr )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( M * sizeof *arr[i] );
  }
}
```

because C arrays are not "first class" objects, and cannot be manipulated and assigned directly, so you *have* to do this through pointers.

Java treats arrays *completely differently* such that you don't need to do the pointer-to-pointer dance at all:

```
T arr[][] = new arr[N];
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  arr[i] = new arr[M];
}
```

I can't think of other use cases off the top of my head, but that should give you a flavor of how you'd translate the C concept to Java.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create an int array even with a size of 1 this way when you access the array it will always refer to the same place in memory as far as your programming is concerned.